# Project on remote drive in VIM

Tags: vim, project-management

Is it possible to create a project based on a remote directory (on an ftp server) in VIM, using the Project plugin?

Comment: I saw a screenshot in wich the author was using the "Project" plugin for managing a project over ftp. That is way I was asking about the possibility to use this plugin for such a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that vim doesn't have internal capabilities to open remote files.  The first poster was correct, netrw is built into later versions of vim and it's awesome.  I use it all the time to edit pages on website via ftp and sometimes over ssh.

Try:

:e ftp://user@machine/path

I seem to remember creating a .netrc file so that I didn't have to type in my user/pass all the time.

man ftp (and search for .netrc assuming you're using vim on unix and not windows)

Comment: When I did this alot I tended to add a shortcut key in my .vimrc file so that I wasn't always typing the full edit line in.

nmap     \b :e ftp://user@machine/path

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I never found that in the documentation. I guess I just skimmed over the "standard plugins" section. Thanks for correcting me. (I would still suggest mounting or distributed version control for anything substantial, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [netrw](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075) plugin. However, in general I've found development easier when files are local and I have a good revision control system (like git) to move files to and from the server.